How to create a command to plot a series of square lattices on a given line?
As the figure below, for a fixed line on a square-lattice layer with the scale of 30*30, it y-coordinate is 12, then I'd like to plot squares on the x-coordinates of 1,6-13,21,28-30, 13 square dots in total.

Then, I'd like to create a command to achieve this effect, that is
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (30,30);
    % replace the following code
    \foreach \x in {1,
        6,7,...,13,
        21,
        28,29,...,30}
    {
        \fill[red] (\x,12) rectangle+ (-1,-1);
    }
    % with 
    % \gridsquare[red]{12}{1,6-13,21,28-30};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Of course, the first optional variable of the command can assign the color of the square dot and its default value is red.
How to create this command? (Maybe expl3 is required, however I could not use it well)

Please provide code, which compiles or shows the problem. Thank you

@MS-SPO The MWE code has been added. Thank you

You can use LaTeX3 to define a parser \meiu_range_to_list:nN
\seq_new:N \l__meiu_tmpa_seq 
\seq_new:N \l__meiu_tmpb_seq
\clist_new:N \l__meiu_tmpa_clist

\cs_set_nopar:Npn \meiu_range_to_list:nN #1#2 {
  \clist_clear:N #2
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__meiu_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__meiu_tmpa_seq 
  {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { ##1 }{ - }
    {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__meiu_tmpb_seq { - } { ##1 }
      \int_step_inline:nnn 
      { \seq_item:Nn \l__meiu_tmpb_seq { 1 } } 
      { \seq_item:Nn \l__meiu_tmpb_seq { 2 } } 
      {
        \clist_put_right:Nn #2 { ####1 }
      }
    }
    {
      \clist_put_right:Nn #2 { ##1 }
    }    
  }
}

\documentclass[tikz, margin = 1cm]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__meiu_tmpa_seq 
\seq_new:N \l__meiu_tmpb_seq
\clist_new:N \l__meiu_tmpa_clist

\cs_set_nopar:Npn \meiu_range_to_list:nN #1#2 {
  \clist_clear:N #2
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__meiu_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__meiu_tmpa_seq 
  {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { ##1 }{ - }
    {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__meiu_tmpb_seq { - } { ##1 }
      \int_step_inline:nnn 
      { \seq_item:Nn \l__meiu_tmpb_seq { 1 } } 
      { \seq_item:Nn \l__meiu_tmpb_seq { 2 } } 
      {
        \clist_put_right:Nn #2 { ####1 }
      }
    }
    {
      \clist_put_right:Nn #2 { ##1 }
    }    
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\gridsquare{O{}mm}
{
  \meiu_range_to_list:nN { #3 } \l__meiu_tmpa_clist
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__meiu_tmpa_clist
  {
    \fill[#1] (##1, #2) rectangle+ (-1,-1);
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (30,30);

    \gridsquare[red]{1}{1, 3, 5-7, 9, 11, 13-15, 17, 19, 21-23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[blue]{2}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[green]{3}{1-5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[yellow]{4}{2, 4-6, 8, 10, 12-14, 16, 18, 20-22, 24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[purple]{5}{1, 3, 5, 7-9, 11, 13, 15, 17-19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[orange]{6}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[pink]{7}{1-3, 5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[brown]{8}{2, 4, 6-8, 10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[cyan]{9}{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19, 21-23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[magenta]{10}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[lime]{11}{1-5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[olive]{12}{2, 4-6, 8, 10, 12-14, 16, 18, 20-22, 24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[teal]{13}{1, 3, 5, 7-9, 11, 13, 15, 17-19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[orange]{14}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[brown]{15}{1-3, 5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[yellow]{16}{2, 4, 6-8, 10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[magenta]{17}{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19, 21-23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[cyan]{18}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[olive]{19}{1-5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[brown]{20}{2, 4-6, 8, 10, 12-14, 16, 18, 20-22, 24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[teal]{21}{1, 3, 5, 7-9, 11, 13, 15, 17-19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[gray]{22}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[pink]{23}{1-3, 5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[brown]{24}{2, 4, 6-8, 10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[olive]{25}{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19, 21-23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[red]{26}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[purple]{27}{1-5, 7, 9, 11-13, 15, 17, 19-21, 23, 25, 27-29}
    \gridsquare[blue]{28}{2, 4-6, 8, 10, 12-14, 16, 18, 20-22, 24, 26, 28, 30}
    \gridsquare[green]{29}{1, 3, 5, 7-9, 11, 13, 15, 17-19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29}
    \gridsquare[pink]{30}{2, 4, 6, 8-10, 12, 14-16, 18, 20, 22-24, 26, 28, 30}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

yield

Edit:
Add a simpler solution:
\usepackage{functional}
\NewDocumentCommand{\gridsquare}{O{red!30!green!20}mm}{
    \def\tmplist{#3}
    \regexReplaceAll{(\d+)-(\d+)}{\1, \1+1 ,..., \2}\tmplist
    \foreach[parse = true] \x in \tmplist
    {
        \fill[#1] (\x,#2) rectangle+ (-1,-1);
    }
}


Great! 为鱼老师打call

If you don't mind staying with the TikZ syntax for the loop:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\sqrs[2]{%
    \foreach \x in {#2}%
        \fill[#1] (\x,12) rectangle+ (-1,-1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (30,30);
    % replace the following code
    \sqrs{teal}{1,6,7,...,13,21,28,29,...,30}
    % with 
    % \gridsquare[red]{12}{1,6-13,21,28-30};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The % inside the \newcommand are needed to end each line with LaTeX macros to avoid unwanted spaces being inserted; however, TikZ doesn't seem to bother ...
